# Duplicate elements of array in the same array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects

I got this array of objects

```
let item = [
  { a: 1 },
  { b: 2 }
]
```

and would like to duplicate array's elements to the same array. Output should be:

```
[
  { a: 1 },
  { b: 2 },
  { a: 1 },
  { b: 2 }
]
```

Can you help?

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Stack Overflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: concat or spread? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: @doctorlove thanks, concat just do the thing `item = item.concat(item);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the first object is the same object as the 3rd object in the array, you can just `concat()` the array to itself.

```js
let item = [
  { a: 1 },
  { b: 2 }
];
let output = item.concat( item );
console.log( JSON.stringify( output ));
console.log( 'Items are the same: ', output[ 0 ] === output[ 2 ] );
```

If the objects have to be different objects with the same properties and values, you'll need to clone all of those objects.

```js
let item = [
  { a: 1 },
  { b: 2 }
];
let clone = collection => collection.map( item => Object.assign( {}, item ));
let output = [ ...clone( item ), ...clone( item ) ];
console.log( JSON.stringify( output ));
console.log( 'Items are the same: ', output[0 ] === output[ 2 ] );
```

See the differences between pass-by-value and pass-by-reference for more information and why this matters.

Answer (score 0):

```
var item = [{ a: 1 }, { b: 2 }];

Array.prototype.duplicate = function() {
  console.log(this.concat(this));
};

item.duplicate();
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let item = [
  { a: 1 },
  { b: 2 }
];

item.forEach(obj => {
  item.push(obj);
})

console.log(item)
```

With a loop